# como reemplazar con replace de java los símbolos ¿ y ¡

Tags: java

Como reemplazo el símbolo ¿ o ¡ con replace, ya que me marca error en el código siguiente:

```
linea = linea.replace('¿','');
```

También he tratado poniendo `'\¿' y '\\\¿'`, y no marca error pero no reemplaza el símbolo.

Comment: Hola. Debes usar las comillas dobles para los strings en Java.

Answer (score 1):

Usa la funcion replace de esta forma

```
String data = "Are you ok?";
System.out.println(data.replace("?",""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu código tiene un problema con las comillas.

El método que estas usando [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) pertenece a la clase String y funciona tal y como se cita en el [javadoc de la clase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) String.

Este método como segundo argumento necesita un **carácter**.

Las comillas simples ' ' (sin nada en el interior) no se consideran un carácter, por lo que te aparece un error.

Puedes solucionar-lo usando el carácter 0 de la tabla ascii: **'\0'** como en el ejemplo siguiente:

```
linea = linea.replace('¿','\0');
```